# iOS - How to make objects draggable to only one direction at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make an `UIViewImage`, and an `UILabel` draggable, and i having some problems to figure out how to make the Views, only draggable at one direction, for example, i want to drag  the views to left(x) or down(y), but never left and down at same time.

I tried to use the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, to see in which direction i should move UP, DOWN or LEFT and RIGHT, but things are not working as i tough.

To make things easier this is what a have on `viewController.h`:

```
///Images
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *mainImage; // Draggable Image
@property (nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDirection; // This will be used on TouchesMoved.

//Label
@property(nonatomic) UILabel *mainLabel; // Draggable Label
```

I'm adding the Swipe recognizer in the `viewDidLoad` Method, just for the Left (for now):

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *detectSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setSwipe:)];
[detectSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:detectSwipe];
```

Here is where i set the "swipeDirection" property:

```
-(void)setSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) { // this is just for testing
    self.swipeDirection = gesture;
    NSLog(@"Gesture = %@", gesture);
    }


}
```

Here is where I'm actually trying to move things (currently only to left):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint currentLocalation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        if (self.swipeDirection.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
            NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
            if (currentLocalation.x < startLocation.x) { // Startlocation is a global CGPoint.
                NSLog(@"Current Y = %f, starting Y = %f", currentLocalation.y, startLocation.y);

                CGFloat distance = startLocation.x - currentLocalation.x;
                CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(160 - distance, 170);
                CGPoint labelPosition = CGPointMake(160 - distance, 390);
                self.mainImage.center = newPosition;
                self.mainLabel.center = labelPosition;

            }

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Other direction");
        }

}
```

What should i do? I'm looking at this from the wrong direction? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a swipe gesture for something it's not fit for (i.e. tracking finger movement and moving views along with the finger). This is exactly what `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is for. Here's an example of how this would work with a pan gesture:

First, attach the gesture recognizer:

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onPan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Then, handle finger movement:

```
-(void)onPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    // Find out how far the finger has moved (+x is right, -x is left, +y is down, -y is up)
    CGPoint movement = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];

    if(movement.x < 0){
        // Finger moved left by movement.x pixels
    }

    if(movement.y > 0){
        // Finger moved down by movement.y pixels
    }

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
}
```

In this example, I'm accepting both left and downwards movement at the same time. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to decide which direction gets precedence if the user drags down and left simultaneously. One suggestion would be to compare the absolute value of the x and y directions, and act on whichever is larger

Comment: You definitely need to know the starting point - or else how do you know, on each entry to this method, where the object began?

Comment: @AdamEberbach `setTranslation:inView:` will reset the translation, so the next time you enter this method, the translation will represent how far the finger has moved since the last time the method was called

Comment: OK, but suppose the pan ends up failing by being a net movement in a direction you don't allow - how do you move the object back to its original position?

Comment: There's nothing about failure cases in the question, I didn't think that was required or expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Pan Gesture recognizer, and lock the direction. I setup a simple typedef for my axis. Default means it hasn't been set yet. When the axis is not set it looks for which direct the user starts off. In this case when the users moves 20 points in one direction it will lock. You want to set a minimum threshold for this to ensure expected results.

```
 typedef enum{
    elAxisUpDown,elAxisLeftRight, elAxisDefault
}elAxis;

-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    CGPoint testPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:

            // @property elAxis
            self.axis = elAxisDefault;

            // @property CGPoints
            self.startingPoint = testPoint;
            self.startingCenter = sender.view.center;
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

            switch (self.axis)
            {
                case elAxisDefault:
                {
                    if (fabsf(testPoint.x-self.startingPoint.x) > fabsf(testPoint.y-self.startingPoint.y) && fabs(testPoint.x-self.startingPoint.x)>20) {
                        self.axis = elAxisLeftRight;
                    }
                    else if (fabsf(testPoint.x-self.startingPoint.x) < fabsf(testPoint.y-self.startingPoint.y) && fabs(testPoint.y-self.startingPoint.y)>20) {
                        self.axis = elAxisUpDown;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case elAxisLeftRight:
                    self.button7.center = CGPointMake(self.startingCenter.x + (testPoint.x - self.startingPoint.x), self.startingCenter.y);

                    break;
                case elAxisUpDown:
                    self.button7.center = CGPointMake(self.startingCenter.x, self.startingCenter.y + (testPoint.y - self.startingPoint.y));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            self.axis = elAxisDefault;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {

    if(panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // record the point of the touch - decide whether the pan is moving an
        // object or misses everything and should be ignored
    } else if(panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // animate the object that might be dragged in the direction you allow, and back,
        // if the gesture point moves around a bit
    } else if(panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // if the gesture ends with a net movement in the allowed direction, finalize the
        // object's move else restore its original position with an animation back 
        // to its original place
    }
}
```

This is the kind of thing you want, in the gesture recogniser handler.